# Error in Chart Director

Tags: php, charts

I am trying to install [Chart Director for PHP](http://www.advsofteng.com/download.html) in Ubuntu 13.04 (64-Bit OS). I have loaded dll files in php extension directory. Also I have added the line 
`extension = "phpchartdir540.dll"` in php.ini file. I have also enabled auto loading in php. I even restarted the system. But I am stuck with the following error.

```
Error Loading ChartDirector for PHP Extension

It appears this PHP system has not loaded the ChartDirector extension by using an extension statement in the PHP configuration file (typically called "php.ini"). An attempt has been made to dynamically load ChartDirector on the fly, but it was not successful. Please refer to the Installation section of the ChartDirector for PHP documentation on how to resolve this problem. 

Error Log

The version and type of PHP in this system does not support dynmaic loading of PHP extensions. All PHP extensions must be loaded by using extension statements in the PHP configuration file. 

System Information
Operating System : Linux ameex-desktop 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64
PHP version : 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
PHP / Web Server interface : apache2handler
PHP configuration file location : "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"
PHP extension directory : "/usr/lib/php5/20100525"
```

Can you please look into this issue an ensure me where I went wrong in Installation?

Answer (score 1):

In your php5 config location, most likely `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` add a file called chart.ini containing `extension=phpchartdir540.dll`